# User model is not finding current user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I used the default `User` model. Inside my `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class TweetModel(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have tried both `get_user_model` and `User`, but they are not working. When I try to write it is saying `owner field is required`. But Token was provided in the request.

Comment: can you add the code for view that the error is showing up in

Comment: Can you please also add the error traceback?

Comment: {
    "owner": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
} Here is the error

Comment: Can you add your view and serializer ? If `{ "owner": [ "This field is required." ] }`, the problem is probably here.

Comment: Are you trying to automatically make tweet's owner = request.user ? Anyway, your problem is not located in the models.py, but more likely in views/serializers.py. Please add these files in your question and tell us what you expect when creating a tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
from django.conf import settings

owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: It didn't work. I didn't set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py file, does it matter?

Comment: from .serializers import TweetSerializer
from .models import TweetModel
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions


# TweetViewset
class TweetViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]
    serializer_class = TweetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TweetModel.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)